# Why is my Java function returning null?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
class Solution {
    Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>();//Created An ArrayList
    public void dfs(int index, int target, List<Integer> choosen, int[] nums)
    {
        if(choosen.size()==3 && target==0 && !map.containsKey(choosen)){
            ret.add(choosen);
            map.put(choosen,0);
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
                System.out.print(list.get(j)+" ");
            System.out.println();
            //map.put(choosen,0);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=index;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            int x = nums[i];
            choosen.add(x);
            target-=x;
            dfs(i+1,target,choosen,nums);
            target+=nums[i];
            choosen.remove(choosen.size()-1);
        }
    }
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> choosen = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        dfs(0,0,choosen,nums);
        return ret; //Returning Null
    }
}
```

Why am i not able to add in "ret"? It's returning null.
I just want to add my choosen list into ret when the condition is true and return ret List.

Comment: `ret` cannot return `null`, because it already initialized before. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's returning null.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that the if statement is checked before 'choosen' value change (when it is empty). 
Try to have the if statement inside the for loop.

Comment: But in if statement it's printing the correct Result. Even choosen is added to ret everytime condition is true. There is some problem in references.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that it is a recursive function. maybe try returning the 'ret' value from inside 'dfs' after the loop and make 'threesum' a void function

Comment: I can't change 'threesum' return type, it's a leetcode problem.

Comment: can you make dfs return 'ret' and in threesum you can declare a variable like this: List<List<Integer>> ratValue =  dfs(0,0,choosen,nums); return ratValue; (instead of return ret;)

Comment: Then what will i return in if condition?

Comment: remove the 'return;' in the if statement and just return ret at the end of the function.